# For a console calculator program, how to split an array of strings (that are numbers) into an array of strings

Tags: java

I'm writing a command line application of a calculator in Java. I need to be able to (as per program requirements) split the array of strings (6+3) into an array of strings? How would that be done?  I know you can use the split method, but I am not really sure how that would work to perform math with them?

On a side note: for this application, how could you make the program accept a variety of different lengths of strings to perform math with them?

```
public class Calculator {
//public String input ="foo";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = ""; // initalize the string
    boolean isOn = true; // used for the while loop...when false, the program will exit.
    String exitCommand = "Exit"; // exit command



    System.out.print("Enter a math problem"); // dummy test
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //input = keyboard.nextLine();
    String[] token = input.split(("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])"));
    while (isOn) {
        for (int i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println(token[i]);
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine()); //This causes an error
            //String[] token = d.split(("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])"));
            //input = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(exitCommand)) {
                // if the user enters exit(ignored case) the boolean goes to false, closing the application
                isOn = false;
            }

           System.out.print(token[0] + d); // shows the math problem(which would by the end of the coding should show the
            //answer to the entered math problem.

        }


    }
}
public void validOperator() {
    ArrayList<String> operator = new ArrayList<String>();
    operator.add("+");
    operator.add("-");
    operator.add("*");
    operator.add("/");

}
public void validOperands(){
    ArrayList<String> operand = new ArrayList<String>();
    operand.add("0");
    operand.add("1");
    operand.add("2");
    operand.add("3");
    operand.add("4");
    operand.add("5");
    operand.add("6");
    operand.add("7");
    operand.add("8");
    operand.add("9");
}
```

}

That is where I am.  Now I cannot figure out how to parse the expression.  I can enter a single number, but not an expression and have the math "math".

Comment: do you accept only number 0 to 9? so if user input is `25 - 4 + 162` consider invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Little nebulous, but assuming your trying to separate operators from numbers

new String("6+3").split("\+") should give you the two numbers.

Split takes a regular expression, so you could put all the operators you're handling in the regex and get all the numbers

Comment: I am taking input from the user, so how (I probably poorly phrased my question...long day at work lol I'm sorry) how would that go about if the user entered 3*4/9+3...etc? This is what I have String userProblem = "2 + 2";
        String[] token = userProblem.split("//s+-*/");

Comment: The regex would have to include any possible operator that you might get.  However, that doesn't mean that gramatically it's correct - if you have +- in succession, you still get an array of numbers, but the syntax doesn't make sense - which would require a simple language parser (which is a whole lot more than splitting)